# Dynamically change DateInterval in Dojo Calendar

Tags: calendar, dojo, dateinterval

Sorry for the mistakes, I'm French.

I use the Dojo calendar and there are some buttons "Today" "4 Days", "Week", "Month"... Is there a javascript function which do like if I clicked on one of these buttons, and thus changes the DateInterval property ? Or there is an other way to do that ?

Thank your for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you want to change the date interval without having to click one of these buttons?
You can do that with the `dateInterval` property which accepts, according to the [API documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dojox/calendar/Calendar#dateInterval), the values: `day`, `week` and `month` (I have no clue how to get the "4 weeks").

This means you can change them by using:

```
registry.byId("myCalendar").set("dateInterval", "day");
```

I also made an example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WjX5g/) (doesn't render properly, but the button does what you want). You can of course change the initiator (I created a seperate button), but it can be anything.

---

**EDIT**: As requested in the comments, you can determine which "view" is chosen by using the following event handler:

```
registry.byId("test").set('onTimeIntervalChange', function(e) {
       console.log(e);
});
```

However, this event will always be executed when the time interval changes, so it will probably also be called when you click a custom button like in my previous example. I have no clue if there's an event handler more suitable to your situation, but the [API documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dojox/calendar/Calendar#dateInterval) will probably be very helpful to you.

Anyways, I updated the JSFiddle which you can find [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WjX5g/1/).

Comment: Well ... perfect, thank you. This is exactly what I wanted!
So, do you know how I could do the opposite ? That is to say, still in javascript, make an event when I click with the mouse on one of the buttons ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the four day calendar set this

```
registry.byId("myCalendar").set("dateInterval", "day");
```

and then this

```
registry.byId("myCalendar").set("dateIntervalSteps", 4);
```